# I'm really confused about Harry Potter's blood status

Tags: harry-potter

I'm confused because Harry Potter is a half-blood even though he was born from a Muggle-born and a pure-blood. Does a Muggle-born count as a Muggle when giving birth or what?

Comment: Depends on whose logic you sympathize with. If you ask the good guys, blood status is irrelevant.

Comment: It´s simple algebra: The average of 2xzero is still zero, the average of one and zero ist 1/2. Of course muggle-borns range somewhat below ordinary humans, the thieving stinks! ;-)